# Is it appropriate to use feedback centrality measures with directed networks?

Tags: r, graph-theory, social-network, igraph

I am analyzing adolescent friendship networks. I am trying to identify key players using different centrality measures, but I am not sure if it is right to use feedback centrality measures (eigenvector, Bonacich's power) with directed networks. I am also not sure how to interpret the scores when using this type of networks: are outgoing and incoming ties considered in the same way?

Below I show a toy example using `R` and the package `igraph`:

```
library(igraph)
g.cd <- graph (c(1,2,2,1,1,5,5,1,5,2,4,3,2,4,2,3,5,6), dir = TRUE)
plot(g.cd)
```

[image]

```
# eigenvector 
(ev <- eigen_centrality(g.cd, scale = FALSE)$vector)
[1] 0.5749643 0.5602605 0.2083357 0.2083357 0.5003244 0.1356179

### bonacich positive
(bp <- power_centrality(g.cd, exp = 0.4, rescale = FALSE))
[1] 1.4506802 1.1755512 0.0000000 0.1750821 1.5757388 0.0000000

# bonacich negative
(bn <- power_centrality(g.cd, exp = -0.4, rescale = FALSE))
[1] 0.1750679 1.8541277 0.0000000 0.7400596 1.4085005 0.0000000

# page rank (this is right with directed networks)
(pr <- page.rank(g.cd)$vector)
[1] 0.1720478 0.1910401 0.2402597 0.1298701 0.1488624 0.1179198
```

Comment: I think that this is more of about properly framing your research: what question are you interested in answering? Once you know that, this will naturally suggest which measurements are most appropriate.

Comment: I want to identify key players, that is, those who have a higher level of  "influence" in the network. The definition of influence is ambiguous, but just to give an example: if you remove those key players from the network you might expect a substantial change in some aggregate variable of interest (e.g., global delinquency in the network). There are different ways to do this. I just want to know if it is technically right to use feedback centrality measures with directed networks and get a better sense of their interpretation (I understand them when using undirected networks).

Comment: You're not going to make a whole lot of traction unless you unambiguously define what influence means for your research. You don't need to define it now and for all time and all applications, but unless you have the meaning of influence fixed in your mind, you'll never be able to state that some centrality measure is better than another in terms of measuring influence.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but that is not the question. Is it appropriate to use feedback centrality measures with directed networks? How does the interpretation change?

Comment: "Is it appropriate to use feedback centrality measures with directed networks?" Surely you can see how a perfectly logical reply is "Appropriate for what purpose?", a question which places you squarely back in the domain of defining your research question and measurable quantities of interest. As posed, your question is "How do I appropriately measure quantities for my research project?", which is somewhat ill-posed. A standard SNA reference like Wasserman & Faust's *Social Network Analysis* might be a helpful place for you to start thinking about this question.